# In my app I can't transfer the picture I took from the Camera to the app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-camera

I made an automobile management application.

I made a vehicle image adding system in the application.

When the Image is selected I want to upload it to firebase and view it.

When I select a picture from the gallery, I can upload and view it, it works without any problems.

At the same time, when I select Camera, I ask for permission and access the camera, but this is the part that doesn't work. After I take the picture from the camera, I return to the application, but the picture I took is not visible. I don't know how to do this.

And.. I don't know how to code.

I'm trying to watch video lessons and adapt them the way I want to make the applications in my head.

This application is the last point I came to.

As far as I saw the answers to the previous questions and the videos, I could not answer this question.

I know it will be difficult, but can you show this ignorant the correct method?

`

```
public class UploadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Uri imageData;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> permissionLauncher;
    private ActivityUploadBinding binding;
    private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Burada Yazan kod ustteki standart titleyi kaldirmak icin.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        // Burada Bitiyor.

        binding = ActivityUploadBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        registerLauncher();


        //Firebase fireStorage icin
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();
```

`

`

```
public void selectImage(View view) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Resim Seciniz");
    builder.setMessage("Resim Kaynagini Seciniz");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            /* if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE); */

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UploadActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(UploadActivity.this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Kameraniza Erismek icin izin gereklidir.",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("izin Ver", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                        }
                    }).show();
                } else {
                    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                }
            } else {
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(takePicture);
            }


            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UploadActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(UploadActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Galerinize erişmek için izin gereklidir.",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("İzin Ver", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //izin isteyecegiz.
                            permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                        }
                    }).show();
                } else {
                    //Ekstra izin isteyecegiz.
                    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            } else {
                // Zaten izin verilmis ise.
                Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(pickPhoto);
            }


            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

private void registerLauncher() {

    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intentFromResult = result.getData();
                if(intentFromResult != null) {
                    imageData = intentFromResult.getData();
                    binding.addCarPicture.setImageURI(imageData);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    permissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
            if(result) {
                Intent intentToGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                activityResultLauncher.launch(intentToGallery);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(UploadActivity.this,"iznine ihtiyacimiz var",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.
You should use request codes, so you can check for it in you activity result method and use some logic to distinguish between taking a picture and selecting a photo from the gallery. Because the Gallery and Camera return different different things.
Second, the image taken from the camera isn't saved. It doesn't have a URI location, because it's just in memory.

```
if(intentFromResult != null) {
       imageData = intentFromResult.getData();
       Bitmap img = (Bitmap)(data.getExtras().get()'data'));
       //Upload img to Database
       //Set imageView from Database
}
```

Here is the documentation on the way you are trying to implement it:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics

Here is the current documentation on how it should be implemented:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

And one last bit to think about. It might be better to use a library so you don't have to write a whole new implementation.
I've used https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker before, it's ok. There might be a better one out there that suits your needs. Take your time and look around.